# Sencha Touch web Mobile application development

Tags: android, sencha-touch

Recently, I switched my platform from Blackberry core application development to Sencha touch web mobile application development. As I am totally blank with this framework, please help me regarding this. What ide, plugins, web-server or browser are the requirements for the development?

One more thing I want to know. As I heard somewhere it is a cross platform framework,
please suggest the initial steps of development with both aspect as Android and iPhone.

Comment: afaik it's javascript framework custom tailored for mobile browsers. So developing for it shouldn't be very different from any other javascript.

Comment: i am agree with your statement Alex but its not like that...i no javascript is not a big task,,but,,,how to get start ,,,for sencha touch. i have done lots of googlin related to it but still i am confused ..regarding ...ide or sencha sdk and webserver,,,,,,as any ide ide which support  javascript ,,can we use....??or eclipse only..here  i a writing a link.....from where i found a pdf,,,,,,

http://www.manning.com/garcia2/

it is helpful but not so much.....

Thanks....

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong wrong link ,,,in my previous comment...the correct link is....http://training.figleaf.com/assets/senchatouchbyol-setup.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sencha touch is a great framework for cross platform development using ExtJS. You can develop an application using javascript and host it on the sever.Whenever a user goes to your URL he will get a look and feel of a native app instead of a web page. 
But in case you do not want to deploy it on the server, you can use senchatouch and phonegap in combination and create an installable app(eg a .apk file for android)

Refer to this tutorial on how to generate native apps with sencha touch :
http://android.amolgupta.in/2011/07/hybrid-applications-using-phonegap-and.html

Comment: thanks Amol..it hepled me....

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to develop a "native web application" have a look at this tutorial: http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

For JavaScript you can use for example Netbeans or IntelliJ. As JavaScript is a client-side language you don't need a webserver. There is also no "Sencha SDK" as it's just the framework (a .js file) you can download for free: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/